# Running containerized application as non-root - Sanity check

Tags: linux, docker, security

I read [this article](https://medium.com/@mccode/processes-in-containers-should-not-run-as-root-2feae3f0df3b#:%7E:text=Most%20containerized%20processes%20are%20application,easy%20method%20to%20limit%20access) about why you shouldn't run containerized applications as root user,
and I'd like someone to confirm my understanding:

### Article brief

The article is basically saying that just as you won't run binaries on your machine
as root, but rather as a least-privileged-required user, you won't run containerized applications as root either.
The recommendation of the author is to create a user with a known uid in the Dockerfile
and run the process as that user.

> The start of the dockerfile should look like
> this:

```
FROM <base image>
RUN groupadd -g 999 appuser && \
    useradd -r -u 999 -g appuser appuser
<br>USER appuser
... <rest of Dockerfile> ..
```

### Validating my understanding, and some questions:

**1. Why bother?**

Ok, I understand that it's not good to run a container process as root,
just like it's not good to run any process as root.
That's why we should create a user in the Dockerfile and run the application process as that user.

But, if it's possible to run:

```
~$ docker run -u 0 some_docker_image
```

then why bother adding a user to my Dockerfile and switch to that user?

The question boils down to the question: What are we "afraid" of? What is the threat?

If the answer is that we're afraid of some untrusted user connected to the system (who is not a sudoer),
then this user can't even run docker containers, unless he is a member of the "docker" group,
in which case - again - he could run the container with -u 0?

So I guess that we're not concerned about the user. We're concerned about the binary itself.
In that case, two possible options exist:
a. The binary is of our creation. In that case: why are we concerned?
b. The binary is of someone else's creation. In that case i can understand why we would like to
switch user.

Am I missing something?

**2. Why "Known uid"?**
Why is that important to specify the uid of the newly created user, and not just name it something?

**3. Why in the start of the Dockerfile?**
Is it important to create+switch to the new user in the beginning of the Dockerfile?
Seemingly, this is an approach that's hard to implement, since usually during the docker build process
you need to run a lot of tasks that require root privileges, such as apt-get install etc.

**4. What about adding a user and adding it to sudoers?**
I have a case in which I need to create a docker image, which when the container runs,
it'll run a ssh server. In order to run the ssh server, you need root privileges.
Is there a point creating a user, adding it to sudoers, and then run the ssh server as root?

Answer (score 0):

1. Running as root in Docker is dangerous for most of the same reasons as running as root directly on the host.  The container has limited Linux privileges so there are some things it can't do (reconfigure the network, reboot the host), but it can do things like overwrite the application code inside the container.

   Nobody's code is absolutely perfect, so one of the big reasons to run as non-root is to minimize the damage possible when a mistake does happen.
2. It doesn't matter what the user ID is, just that it's not 0.  There's an argument to make it different from any uid the host might be using, but since your image could run on any host, it's just a guess.
3. You should create the user at the start of the Dockerfile, since that setup will change infrequently and Docker layer caching can skip it.  But, you should use the `USER` directive and switch to the user at the *end* of the Dockerfile, after `COPY`ing code in and `RUN`ning the build.  Do not `RUN chown ...` to make the non-root user own the code: you want most files to be owned by root, so that the non-root user can't overwrite them.

   (In a compiled language, with a multi-stage build, you can consider the Dockerfile equivalent of the `./configure; make; sudo make install` sequence, switching to a non-privileged user to do the build.  I haven't seen this pattern in many Dockerfiles but I'd recognize it if I saw it.)
4. Do not add a user to `/etc/sudoers`.  There are a couple of good reasons for this.  The most basic one is that a container only runs a single process, and as already discussed we probably don't want it to be root.  You can either configure it with no password (in which case you might as well be root) or hard-code a password in plain text in your Dockerfile (also a bad idea).  You also usually don't want to run `sudo` inside a script (its behaviors of putting up random password prompts and hiding environment variables can cause trouble), and so correspondingly don't want to `RUN sudo ...` in a Dockerfile.

   If you need to break into a container to debug it, you can always `docker exec -u root ...` to get a root shell there.